# Proof: linearly dependence for particular set in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem that I can't seem to solve is:

> Let $S$ be the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ with exactly $2$ entries equal to $1$ and all the rest of its entries equal to $0$. Is $S$ linearly independent?

First, I know it seems dumb but I don't understand if the entries are the vectors, or the entries are in the vectors.

Second, I tried to figure out this problem, considering that the entries are the entries in the vectors.
If put in a matrix form, there must be at least $2$ rows or columns which entries are all zeros, so $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m$ are linearly dependent. Therefore, $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ is linearly dependent.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The set $S$ is $\left\{\biggl(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{smallmatrix}\biggr),
\biggl(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\biggr),
\biggl(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\biggr),
\biggl(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\biggr),
\biggl(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\biggr),
\biggl(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\biggr)\right\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries are *in* the vectors. There are ${4\choose 2}=6$ such vectors. Any set of 5 or more vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ must be linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

$S$ is the set of the following vectors:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, do you think they are independent?